# Can I set identity of my WCF service to run as 'Network Service' so it can reach shared network folders?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, application-pool

When debugging WCF service I need to use the remote share that stores our test data. But, since I host it on a local machine in IIS5 it doesn't have something like an application pool identity as found in IIS6 or 7, so the process running my WCF doesn't have permissions to reach it.

How can I configure my WCF service to use a Network Identity so I can have access to shared folders in network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to configure it in machine.config. Try to set `processModel` element to:

```
<processModel userName="Network Service" password="AutoGenerate" ... />
```

It will affect all ASP.NET applications hosted in IIS.

Comment: Very nice idea, but unfortunatelly it's a no-go: from evenvwr - "aspnet_wp.exe could not be launched because the username and/or password supplied in the processModel section of the config file are invalid."

Comment: The correct form is: `<processModel userName="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" password="AutoGenerate" autoConfig="true"/>` It doesn't work with just "Network Service"